# How do i view the index version of a file before it is committed?

Tags: git

I have just performed `git add --interactive`, so the index version of some files is different than the working-directory versions.  Instead of doing `git diff --cached`, I want to actually dump the contents of each file in the index, but I can't find a command to do that.  I should think that there would be something like `git show INDEX:filename...`, but "INDEX" is not a valid object name.

I was able to do `git ls --cached`, then `git show <hash>`, but there should be a more straightforward method to see what you are committing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, simply:

```
git show :filename
```

If you have multiple index versions (such as in a merge conflict situation) you can view versions in different index slots with:

```
git show :1:filename
git show :2:filename
git show :3:filename
```

In most other situations only slot 0 is populated and `:0:filename` is the identifer for the cached version of the file. `:filename` is a shorthand for `:0:filename`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **test** the version of project that you have stashed in the index, you can use
[`git stash --keep-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (see "*Testing partial commits*" section in [git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) manpage).